# How to check CPI (cycles per instruction) or IPC (instructions per cycle) on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, operating-system, cpu, benchmarking

I just learned the concept of CPI and IPC and I am curious how to check them on Mac OS. I search it online but I cannot find an answer. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Performance Counters API in OS X](//stackoverflow.com/q/39306968), but that doesn't have a useful answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Record values of Performance Monitor Counters (PM events) on OS X without Instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536551/record-values-of-performance-monitor-counters-pm-events-on-os-x-without-instru)

Comment: That question points out that XCode can profile with hardware performance counters.  (Which can count cycles and instructions, and presumably do the math for you to show you IPC.  And probably more usefully, uops/cycle as well to see how close to the 4/clock front-end issue bandwidth bottleneck (on Intel CPUs until IceLake) you are.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the information, I will try the XCode approach.